# Kernel preshef is a (pre)sheaf

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

I'm not the first one asking for clarifications on the subject.
But my question is slightly different, and possibly easier to answer.

Suppose $\varphi\colon \mathcal{F}\to \mathcal{G}$ be a morphism of sheaves on a topological space $X$, so that $V\subseteq U$ (inclusion of open subsets) implies $\varphi(V)\circ \rho^\mathcal{F}_{UV}=\rho^\mathcal{G}_{UV}\circ \varphi(U)$, where  $\rho^\mathcal{F}_{UV}\colon \mathcal{F}(U)\to\mathcal{F}(V)$, $\rho^\mathcal{G}_{UV}\colon \mathcal{G}(U)\to\mathcal{G}(V)$ restriction maps.
The *kernel presheaf* of $\varphi$ works as follows: $U\mapsto \mathrm{Ker}(\varphi(U))\subseteq \mathcal{F}(U)$.
This means that $V\subseteq U$ implies $\rho^\mathcal{F}_{UV}\colon \mathrm{Ker}(\varphi(U))\to \mathrm{Ker}(\varphi(V))$, restriction to the kernel of the above restriction map.

So I would like to prove that $\rho^\mathcal{F}_{UV}(\mathrm{Ker}(\varphi(U)))=\mathrm{Ker}(\varphi(V))$.
I easily proved $(\subseteq)$, but I have no idea for the converse $(\supseteq)$.
Can someone help me, please?

Comment: There's no reason to require that the restriction morphism is surjective on the kernel of phi. You have only to check that the image is contained in Ker$\phi(V) $, which you have already done

Comment: It’s false: it’s very possible that *every* section of $\mathcal{F}(U)$ restricts to a zero section of $V$, even though $\mathcal{F}(V) \neq 0$. In this case, we get a contradiction when $\mathcal{G}=0$.

Comment: I see. For some reason I thought it should be the case, but now I understand neither I need this fact nor it is true. Thank you to you both.

Comment: @LBJFS No problem. If you're interested in sheaves with restriction morphisms all surjective they exist and they are called flabby sheaves. They play a central role in the cohomology of sheaves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's not true unless $\mathcal{F}$ is special since it's not you are just free not to verify

Comment: I upvoted, but I don't understand very much what you just wrote. Can you elaborate further, please?

Comment: To be honest, I am just in a 12 years old mood, but the content is serious. As others wrote, restriction is not necessarily surjective in general: this kind of sheaves are called flabby and plays a prominent role. Actually, it's very cool to have a flabby kernel, since the exact sequence yields an exact sequence in global sections. Thus, whenever you have a map of sheaves which is surjective on small opens but not on global sections, the Kernel won't be flabby.